# How to programmatically add textField to a scroll view

Tags: swift, uiview, scroll, uiscrollview

I have a button on my storyboard. This button is inside a view and that view is inside a scroll view.

What I am trying to do sounds relatively simple: When the button is pressed, the button moves down a little bit and a textField appears where the button had previously been.

However, what happens is the button animates, but then returns to its original position, instead of staying moved, and the textField appears as it should.

Because the position of the appearing textField is dependent on the position of the button, pressing the button multiple times simply places a bunch of textfields on top of each other.

Here is a picture of what happens:

[my Screen:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eT9kX.png)

Here is the code I am running when the button is pressed:

@IBAction func addIngredientButtonPressed(sender: UIButton) {

```
contentView.bounds.size.height += addIngredientLabel.bounds.height

scrollView.contentSize.height += addIngredientLabel.bounds.height


//Create Text Field and Set Initial Properties
let newIngredientTextField = UITextField(frame: CGRectMake(self.addIngredientLabel.frame.minX as CGFloat, self.addIngredientLabel.frame.midY as CGFloat, self.addIngredientLabel.bounds.width,self.addIngredientLabel.bounds.height * 0.60))

newIngredientTextField.font = UIFont.systemFontOfSize(15.0)
newIngredientTextField.placeholder = "ADD INGREDIENT HERE"
newIngredientTextField.contentHorizontalAlignment = UIControlContentHorizontalAlignment.Left

newIngredientTextField.alpha = 0.0

scrollView.addSubview(newIngredientTextField)



UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5) { () -> Void in

    self.addIngredientLabel.center.y += self.addIngredientLabel.bounds.height
    newIngredientTextField.alpha = 1.0

}
```

}

Note:** the length is also being added successfully to the screen, but the button is not staying moved. So in the screenshot above you can indeed scroll up and down **

I noticed that if you comment out the top 2 lines of code, the ones that add height to the contentView and the scrollView, you get almost the right behavior. The button moves and stays moved, the textField appears in the right spot, but if you keep pressing, it won't let you add more textFields than the screen size will hold.

Here is a picture of what happens if you comment out the top two lines. The button won't do anything more if you keep pressing it more:

[screen filled:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lz0yT.png)

I found lots of tutorials that tell you how to add more content than can fit into one screen using the storyboard and setting the inferred metrics to free form, but I have not found anyone trying to add elements dynamically like I am.

Answer (score 0):

You appear to have a `contentView` -- presumably a direct subview of your `scrollView`, but you're adding the `newIngredientTextField` directly to your `scrollView` rather than to your `contentView`.

When you increase the `bounds.size.height` of the `contentView`, it decreases its `frame.origin.y` by half as much (to keep its `center` in the same place). As your original button is presumably a subview of this `contentView`, that will cause it to move independently of the newly-added text field.

In other words, write:

`contentView.frame.size.height += addIngredientLabel.bounds.height`

rather than

`contentView.bounds.size.height += addIngredientLabel.bounds.height`

and

`contentView.addSubview(newIngredientTextField)`

rather than

`scrollView.addSubview(newIngredientTextField)`.

Comment: I am afraid implementing your recommendations resulted in the same behavior. You are correct in your assumption that the view called contentView is a direct sub view of the scrollView. If you could see my viewController hierarchy you would see the contentView is a child of the ScrollView and the scrollView is a child of the main view. Could the solution be to animate the constraints instead of the button called addIngredientLabel itself? I wish I had a more visual way to figure out what the views are doing when there frames are changed.

Comment: The other thing to try would be to put the changing of the `frame` of the `contentView` and the `contentSize` of the `scrollView` into the animation block.